# How can we make a prediction using Scikit-Learn Classifiers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, classification

I can easily train and test a classifier using the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Load Library
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier,AdaBoostClassifier,GradientBoostingClassifier# Step1: Create data set


# Define the headers since the data does not have any
headers = ["symboling", "normalized_losses", "make", "fuel_type", "aspiration",
           "num_doors", "body_style", "drive_wheels", "engine_location",
           "wheel_base", "length", "width", "height", "curb_weight",
           "engine_type", "num_cylinders", "engine_size", "fuel_system",
           "bore", "stroke", "compression_ratio", "horsepower", "peak_rpm",
           "city_mpg", "highway_mpg", "price"]

# Read in the CSV file and convert "?" to NaN
df = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data",
                  header=None, names=headers, na_values="?" )
df.head()

df.columns

df_fin = pd.DataFrame({col: df[col].astype('category').cat.codes for col in df}, index=df.index)
df_fin


X = df_fin[['symboling', 'normalized_losses', 'make', 'fuel_type', 'aspiration',
       'num_doors', 'body_style', 'drive_wheels', 'engine_location',
       'wheel_base', 'length', 'width', 'height', 'curb_weight', 'engine_type',
       'num_cylinders', 'engine_size', 'fuel_system', 'bore', 'stroke',
       'compression_ratio', 'horsepower', 'peak_rpm']]
y = df_fin['city_mpg']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


# Fit a Decision Tree model
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Now, how can I make a prediction of the target variable (dependent variable) based on the independent variables?

Something like this should work, I think, but it doesn't...

```
clf.predict([[2,164,'audi','gas','std','four','sedan','fwd','front',99.8,176.6,66.2,54.3,2337,'ohc','four',109,'mpfi',3.19,3.4,10,102,5500,24,30,13950,]])
```

If we leave numerics as numerics, and put quotes around labels, I would like to predict the dependent variable, but I can't, because of the labeled data. If the data was all numerics, and this was a regression problem, it would work!! My question is...how can we feed in numbers and labels, like a real person would understand, rather than using the the numerics that the labels are converted into. I've gotta believe, labels are converted into numerics (one hot encoding, catagorical codes, or whatever) before the training and testing is done, right.

Here is the error message that I'm getting.

```
clf.predict([[2,164,'audi','gas','std','four','sedan','fwd','front',99.8,176.6,66.2,54.3,2337,'ohc','four',109,'mpfi',3.19,3.4,10,102,5500,24,30,13950,]])
C:\Users\ryans\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:450: UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but DecisionTreeClassifier was fitted with feature names
  warnings.warn(

Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [20] in <cell line: 1>
    clf.predict([[2,164,'audi','gas','std','four','sedan','fwd','front',99.8,176.6,66.2,54.3,2337,'ohc','four',109,'mpfi',3.19,3.4,10,102,5500,24,30,13950,]])

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py:505 in predict
    X = self._validate_X_predict(X, check_input)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py:471 in _validate_X_predict
    X = self._validate_data(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr", reset=False)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:577 in _validate_data
    X = check_array(X, input_name="X", **check_params)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:856 in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'audi'
```

Comment: post the traceback please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a map of your columns values with the corresponding categorical values:

```
col_dictionary = {}
for col in df:
    dictionary = dict(enumerate(df[col].astype('category').cat.categories))
    col_dictionary[col] = {v: k for k, v in dictionary.items()}
```

obtaining:

```
{'symboling': {-2: 0, -1: 1, 0: 2, ..., 3: 5}, 'normalized_losses': {65.0: 0, 74.0: 1, ..., 197.0: 48, 231.0: 49, 256.0: 50}, 'make': {'alfa-romero': 0, 'audi': 1, 'bmw': 2, 'chevrolet': 3, 'dodge': 4, ..., 'volkswagen': 20, 'volvo': 21}, 'fuel_type': {'diesel': 0, 'gas': 1}, 'aspiration': {'std': 0, 'turbo': 1}, 'num_doors': {'four': 0, 'two': 1}, 'body_style': {'convertible': 0, 'hardtop': 1, 'hatchback': 2, 'sedan': 3, 'wagon': 4}, 'drive_wheels': {'4wd': 0, 'fwd': 1, 'rwd': 2}, 'engine_location': {'front': 0, 'rear': 1}, 'wheel_base': {86.6: 0, 88.4: 1, ..., 115.6: 51, 120.9: 52}, 'length': {141.1: 0, 144.6: 1, ..., 202.6: 73, 208.1: 74}, 'width': {60.3: 0, 61.8: 1, ..., 59.1: 47, 59.8: 48}, 'curb_weight': {1488: 0, 1713: 1, 1819: 2, ..., 4066: 170}, 'engine_type': {'dohc': 0, 'dohcv': 1, 'l': 2, 'ohc': 3, 'ohcf': 4, 'ohcv': 5, 'rotor': 6}, 'num_cylinders': {'eight': 0, 'five': 1, 'four': 2, 'six': 3, 'three': 4, 'twelve': 5, 'two': 6}, 'engine_size': {61: 0, 70: 1, 79: 2, ..., 304: 41, 308: 42, 326: 43}, 'fuel_system': {'1bbl': 0, '2bbl': 1, '4bbl': 2, 'idi': 3, 'mfi': 4, 'mpfi': 5, 'spdi': 6, 'spfi': 7}, 'bore': {2.54: 0, 2.68: 1, ..., 3.94: 37}, 'stroke': {2.07: 0, 2.19: 1, ..., 3.9: 34, 4.17: 35}, 'compression_ratio': {7.0: 0, 7.5: 1, ..., 23.0: 31}, 'horsepower': {48.0: 0, 52.0: 1, ..., 288.0: 58}, 'peak_rpm': {4150.0: 0, ..., 6600.0: 22}, 'city_mpg': {13: 0, 14: 1, 15: 2, ..., 49: 28}, 'highway_mpg': {16: 0, ..., 53: 28, 54: 29}, 'price': {5118.0: 0, 5151.0: 1, ..., 41315.0: 184, 45400.0: 185}}
```

And then use this map to convert the array you want to predict:

```
prediction_values = [2, 164, 'audi', 'gas', 'std', 'four', 'sedan', 'fwd', 'front', 99.8, 176.6, 66.2, 54.3, 2337, 'ohc', 'four', 109, 'mpfi', 3.19, 3.4, 10, 102, 5500, 30, 13950]
to_predict = []
for (column, value) in zip(X.columns, prediction_values):
    to_predict.append(col_dictionary[column][value])
to_predict_df = pd.DataFrame([to_predict], columns=X.columns)
clf.predict([to_predict_df.iloc[0].values])
```

Comment: This is close, but when I run it, I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [63] in <cell line: 3>
    to_predict.append(col_dictionary[column][value])

KeyError: 13950

Let's say I want to predict the value in the last column, which is 'price'. I can't give the model 13950 as predicted price, because this what I want to predict. If I remove the 13950 and run it again, I get this: 

ValueError: 25 columns passed, passed data had 24 columns

Comment: This is just an example of input. You have to choose which columns you want to use at the training phase and insert them in the X variable, then your target column in y (price in this case). For prediction, you have to pass X columns and you should get the price. The error you are seeing is because you are not defining the same columns in X and predict method.

Comment: So, how can  fix this problem? Did you guys actually get it to work?

Comment: Just put: 
X = df_fin[["symboling", "normalized_losses", ... , "horsepower", "peak_rpm",
           "city_mpg", "highway_mpg"]],
y = df_fin['price']
then:
prediction_values = [2, 164, 'audi', 'gas', 'std', 'four', 'sedan', 'fwd', 'front', 99.8, 176.6, 66.2, 54.3, 2337, 'ohc', 'four', 109, 'mpfi', 3.19, 3.4, 10, 102, 5500, 24, 30]

Comment: I tried that and got this.

ValueError: 25 columns passed, passed data had 24 columns

Am I missing something here?

Comment: as mentioned before you have to check your columns...
in headers and prediction_values you have "highway_mpg" while in X you are not passing it. if this is wanted you have to remove it also from prediction_values otherwise add it to X.

Comment: I made the adjustment that you recommended. Didn't see that before. Thanks! So, this is the final result? 
clf.predict([to_predict_df.iloc[0].values])
Out[198]: array([135], dtype=int16)

Comment: I though I could pass in something like: prediction_values = [2, 164, 'audi', 'gas',etc...,5500, 24, 30]. Then it would spit out the price. As soon as clf.predict sees 'audi', it throws an error, because it's a string. If I have to enter the cat.codes of 'audi' it gets really hard to read/interpret.

Comment: Sklearn unfortunately doesn't directly manage categorical features, you have to encode them. The answer I propose you is a wrap method for predict. In this way you can pass the vector in your human readable way while it translates the vector to an input that is understandable by the model.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for sharing your knowledge here!!